# Display HTML Starting tag in Razor view block

Tags: c#

I want to display an HTML `div` tag in a `for` loop when two elements are true. Thus, I have to display the starting `div` like this:

```
*.chtml below
Html.Raw("<div class=\"additional-options clearfix\" style=\"display: block;\">");
```

and display the end tag when the other element is true.

The result is that the div is NOT printed out in HTML

Is there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if you ever need to you print out plain text or html tag that has no closing tag you need to use the @: construct. For example:

```
 <div>
    @if (Model.IsTrue)
    {
       @:Statement is true.
       @:<img src="/Images/cool.jpg" alt="" />
    } else {
       <span>Statement is not true.</span>
    }
 </div>
```

Notice how I need to use @: to exit C# code and enter HTML mode. However when I have an HTML element with open close tags then there is no need to use escape character.

Comment: You meant I can print the div like this @:<div id="1">text here?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Razor, you should just be able to write HTML directly, as in:

```
<body>
    <span>This is some normal HTML</span>

    @{
        Boolean fork = true;
        Int32[] numbers = new Int32[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};

        if(fork)
        {
            <div>If fork is true, this will display</div>

            foreach(Int32 number in numbers)
            {
                <span>@number</span>   
                <span>@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("<Tag>This is a nonsense tag </Tag>")</span>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div>If fork is false, this will display</div>
        }
    }

    <span>This is more normal HTML</span>
</body>
```

Just make sure to use `@{ }` to escape from HTML to code (or in some cases back again).

Comment: I know all that. I cannot see the answer.

Comment: Sorry, about that. Are you just trying to do `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` (as above)?

Comment: Isn't it true that HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() must be used before HtmlDecode() for string?

Comment: If you're trying to display a raw tag, that should work for you. Honestly though, I'm not entiiiirely sure what you're after.